# Cofibration and retraction

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am working on cofibrations for an assignment and I am looking in the book *Topology and geometry* by Bredon and he states an inclusion map is a cofibration if and only if $A\times I \cup X\times\{0\}$ is a retract of $X\times I$, how are those two in anyway different when $A\subset X$ and $0\in I$? The union of those two sets should be identical to $X\times I$ or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right you're asking why it isn't true that 
$$A \times I \cup X \times \{0\} = X \times I$$
for every $A \subseteq X$.

That's just a set theoretic fact: consider for example $X=I$ and $A=\{0\}$,
then
$$A \times I \cup X \times \{0\}=\{0\} \times I \cup I \times \{0\}$$
which isn't clearly equal to $X \times I = I \times I$, since $(1,1)$ doesn't belong either to $\{0\} \times I$ or $I \times \{0\}$.